# Upload data, put the column names in radiobutton and show the table in Shiny

Tags: shiny

I want to upload a .csv file. Then, update the radio button choices as column names of the uploaded file and then, through that radio button choose which columns to show. The problem is whenever I run the code, it gives me this error.

P.S.1. Is there any way to read the data before we run this app? like in another app?

[image]

```
 library(shiny)
 ui = basicPage(
    fileInput('uploadedcsv', "", accept = '.csv'),

    radioButtons(
      "column1",
      "select columns",
      choices = "",
      inline = T
    ),
    radioButtons(
      "column2",
      "select columns",
      choices = "",
      inline = T
    ),
    dataTableOutput('mytable')
  )

 server = function(session,input, output) {

    z <- reactive({
      infile <- input$uploadedcsv

      if (is.null(infile))
        return(NULL)

      read.csv(infile$datapath, header = TRUE, sep = ",")
    })

    observe({
      vchoices <- names(z())
      updateRadioButtons(session, "column1", choices = vchoices)
      updateRadioButtons(session, "column2", choices = vchoices)
    })
    z <- reactive(z[,c(input$column1,input$column2)])
    output$mytable = renderDataTable(z())
  }
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

z is the closure that is not sub-settable:

```
z <- reactive(z[,c(input$column1,input$column2)])
```

*z* is a reactive function returned by your first assignment. It is not subsettable (you cannot index it) because it is a function. You can call *z* and index the result as in *renderDataTable* below. *renderDataTable* will call *z()* and is reactive to changes in *z*'s output, *input$column1* and *input$column2*.

```
server = function(input, output, session) {

  # z is reactive to a change in the input data

  z <- reactive({
    infile <- input$uploadedcsv

    if (is.null(infile))
      return(NULL)

    read.csv(infile$datapath, header = TRUE, sep = ",")
  })

  observe({
    vchoices <- names(z())
    updateRadioButtons(session, "column1", choices = vchoices)
    updateRadioButtons(session, "column2", choices = vchoices)
  })

  # renderDataTable is reactive to a change in the input data
  # or the selected columns

  output$mytable = renderDataTable({
    z()[,c(input$column1, input$column2)]
  })
}
```

Comment: Regarding coding style, using renderDataTable with only a reactive inside seems redundant, I'd just write `output$mytable = renderDataTable({ data()[,c(input$column1, input$column2)] })`

Comment: @shosaco Thank you. But, I preferred Mike's previous answer. I coded that way because my goal wasn't the table in the first place. I used the table to see how my data looks like. Later, I use the dataframe in another function to plot a chart